# Display Text in TextView and Save it in a Cache?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am getting news data from a url as a JSONString. The JSONString contains news objects and I want to get the title and the message, and display them on a TextView. How can I display the Title and the message in TextView and save it in a cache?

```
public class SEVData extends IntentService { 
    ...

    @Override 
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) { 
        while (serviceIsRunning) { 
            int id_s = 0; 
            String url0 = "http://172.17.100.2/mham/sendapp.php?co>"+id_s;
            String newsData; 
            try { 
                URL url = new URL(url0); 
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream()); 
                newsData = getJSONString(in);
                in.close(); 
                JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(newsData); 
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("date"); 
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { 
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                    String id= jsonObject.optString("id"); 
                    String title = jsonObject.optString("title"); 
                    String message = jsonObject.optString("message");
                } 
            } // catch unrelated
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Format your code & add some details, I tried formatting it, didn't work coz lack of details

Comment: Sorry for that I need to save it insharedpreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add SharedPreference keys like so in the for loop:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { 
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
    String id= jsonObject.optString("id"); 
    String title = jsonObject.optString("title"); 
    String message = jsonObject.optString("message");
    editor.putString(title, message);
    editor.apply();
}
```